# Do the different levels of treatment in a completely randomized design come from different population?

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, anova, t-test, experiment-design

Suppose in a completely randomized design , a treatment *A* have four levels. When we check whether the means of four levels are statistically significant ,i.e.,
$$H_0:\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu_3=\mu_4$$
$$\text{Vs}$$
$$H_1:\mu_i\ne \mu_j;\forall i\ne j; i=1,\ldots,4;j=1,\ldots,4;$$

are those levels from four different populations as their means are different ? Or they have come from same population ?

I suppose they are from different population as we write,$$y_i\sim NID(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$$

So does it imply :

- $2$ different sample coming from $2$ different population can be either statistically significant or not; and
- $2$ different population  coming from *same*  population should be statistically *insignificant*.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign people randomly to treatments, then the people come from the same population and there is no test needed or possible of whether they came from the same population: They did.

If you then compare these groups on 100 measures, approximately 5 of those will show significant differences.

That's what a p value *means* - if you fling poop at a wall, what percentage do you want to stick?

This is one reason that you might still want to include covariates in a randomized experiment: Groups can vary, even if they are randomized.

Comment: In Randomization (one of the three principles of design), don't we assume treatment should be randomly allocated to experimental units ,ie , we assign treatments randomly to people.

Comment: How should i know , when i need to assign people randomly ? And when to assign treatments randomly ? If i assign people randomly, it implies the people come from the same population.Why?and when should be it from different population ?

Comment: Because that's what random assignment means. It's pretty much always better to have a randomized design, but it is often impossible to do so.

Comment: If we take homogeneous experimental units,then why do we need to concern about whether we randomly allocate experimental unit or randomly allocate treatment?

Comment: Would you please give me reference so that i can clear about random assignment . I am not understanding the first line of your answer.

Comment: If i am able to assign people randomly to treatments, then i don't need any test. Then what would be the result of my experiment? And if it is not always possible to do a randomized design, then what is the benefit of it and what is the alternative ?

Comment: You need to read a book on experimental design; any book on the subject will cover all this. I don't have any particular one that I like best.

Comment: I agree with the OP that the first line of this answer is puzzling.  Whether or not the groups come from the same population, what bearing does that have on whether one can apply a statistical test?  The second line is difficult to fathom, too: what is a "measure"? Apparently these 100 "measures" are assumed to be independent in order for you to draw the conclusion about only five showing significant differences: how is that possible when you are using the same set of "these groups" in all 100 tests?  And I will try to forget I ever read the third line... .

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion; I meant a test of whether they come from the same population.  I will edit my answer.